# Vue bind value to object by key when button click

Tags: javascript, html, button, vue.js, onclick

I am new to Vue, i want to create some buttons from my data and display their information when clicking the button. The object 'pets' has two keys: id and info. (My data is larger and my code more complicated, i was trying to simplify it here.)

```
data() {
  return {
    selectedpet: undefined,
    message: undefined,
    pets : [
      {
        id: 1,
        info: "yellow"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        info: "brown"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        info:"huge"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I created some buttons by the data with the 'id' displayed on the buttons, and the variable 'selectedpet' will record the clicked button:

```
<div v-for="pet in pets :key="pet.id">
<button @click="selectedpet = pet">
    <i>{{pet.id}}</i>
</button>
```

What i need to do is to create a div, which text will display the 'info' of the clicked button. How can i set the message to the 'info' of the click button?

```
<div id="printselectedpet">Selected pet: {{ message }}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my solution

```js
new Vue({
el:"#app",

data:{
message:"I am initial message",
buttonz:[{id:1,info:"this is first button"},{id:2,info:"this is secoind button"},{id:3,info:"this is my third button"}]
},
methods:{
getMyKey(myKey){
if(myKey != undefined){
this.message = this.buttonz[myKey].info;
}else{
this.message = "Cannot Get the Key";

}
}
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div>
{{message}}
</div>
<button v-for="(but,index) in buttonz" :key="but.id" @click="getMyKey(index)">
My ID: {{but.id}}
</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for `message` data

```
<div id="printselectedpet">Selected pet: {{ selectedpet.info }}</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to set pet.info to message.

See below code:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el : "#vueRoot",
  data: {
    selectedpet: undefined,
    message: undefined,
    pets : [
      {
        id: 1,
        info: "yellow"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        info: "brown"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        info:"huge"
      }
    ]
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vueRoot">
  <div v-for="pet in pets" :key="pet.id">
    <button @click="message = pet.info">
        <i>{{pet.id}}</i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div id="printselectedpet" v-if="message">Selected pet: {{ message }}</div>
</div>
```